# Draggable data points in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, plot, user-interface, vba

I know Microsoft removed draggable points in 2007, but I need to get that function back.

So far, I've got the MouseDown and MouseUp events trapped, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to scale the cursor's movement (which is measured in pixels) to a change of the selected point (arbitrary scale)

Using VBA, how can I find the height/width of a chart as well as each axis' max & min values?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this addin MS posted?
http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2009/11/02/excel-add-in-for-manipulating-points-on-charts-mpoc.aspx